# QTP for Flash - any recommendations for a useful plugin?

Tags: flash, testing, automation, seetest

I am using QTP and need to test a flash application. I found 3 plugins for this purpose: Adobe's actionscript, Experitest's SeeTest and Riatest. Adobe's was heay duty learning and i gave up...can anyone recommend one otfthe other options? or provide additional options?

Comment: The title is a little bit misleading. You don't ask for a plugin for QTP, but you ask for flex automation in general. There were other questions on this topic, you can find some answers there

Answer (score 2):

Adobe (Macromedia) Flex applications is handled by Adobe. Adobe has released Flex Builder 3.0; this release includes the QuickTest Professional Flex add-in. The add-in was developed using QuickTest Professional's Test Extensibility Architecture functionality. The Flex add-in is developed and owned by Adobe.
Hewlett Packard does not support the Adobe Flex add-in, therefore I suggest contacting Adobe (http://www.adobe.com) to see about availability, support details, and pricing.

Adobe is providing the add-in via an automation package that is shipped with Flex Builder 3 Professional. Basic information on the automation package with QuickTest Professional integration is here:

http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_fb.html
http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/upgrade/

Users can download the automation package with QuickTest Professional integration here: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flex

A specific Adobe license is required and needs to be requested from Adobe. No specific Flex license is required on the QuickTest Professional side.

Note: Support for the Flex add-in is being provided by Adobe. Customers/end-users need to contact the Adobe support organization for help with problems or questions related to the Flex add-in.

From the Flex Builder 3 release notes (for an updated version, contact Adobe):

*Requirements for Using the QTP Plug-in 
To test applications with Flex Automated Testing and the QTP agent, you must install the following:
HP QuickTest Professional 9.1 (no support for Smart Identification), available from HP
 
HP QuickTest Professional 9.2 and patch 1701 or later if you want Smart Identification support.

Adobe Flex 3 Plug-in for HP QuickTest Professional
 
Microsoft Internet Explorer, version 6 or later 

Flash Player ActiveX control, version 9.0.28.0 or higher 

For any questions regarding support of Flex, and QuickTest Professional, please contact Adobe for the latest information:*

Comment: Hi Jonas. thank you for the detailed and insightful answer. I have few questions in this regard: (1) i am heading the automation team i our ocmpany and some of the team are not very storng in programming. How simple to operate is the adobe tool? (2) do you know what is the cost of the tooland if the support is included?